# The noun "alternative"

Tags: latin, loanwords

If I am not mistaken, the noun *alternative* has roots in the Latin word *alter*, which translates to: *the other (**of two**)*.

My question would be: why does the word *alternative* have plural in English? It is clear from the definition of *alter* that to every possible choice there can be only **one** alternative?

To quote Oxford Dictionaries ([link](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/alternative)):

> Some traditionalists maintain that you can only have a maximum of two alternatives, because the word alternative comes from Latin alter ‘other (of two)’) and that uses where there are more than two alternatives are wrong. Such uses are, however, normal in modern standard English.

If the uses where there are more than two alternatives are considered to be wrong, why are they normal in modern standard English? Any thoughts or comments would be much appreciated.

*Remark.* It is the same in several other languages (German and Croatian being two examples that I am aware of).

Comment: You must give a sensible and unskewed portion of quotes. <<Some traditionalists maintain that you can only have a maximum of two alternatives, because the word alternative comes from Latin alter ‘other (of two)’) and that uses where there are more than two alternatives are wrong. Such uses are, however, normal in modern standard English. >> Usage trumps etymology and outmoded tradition.

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth: Thanks, I corrected the quote. I would disagree that this is a case of outmoded tradition. It is more probable that most people are not aware of the meaning of the original Latin word. But I find it interesting that dictionaries contain plural of "alternative".  So the question is whether "alternatives" is just a common usage, or is it also grammatically correct?

Comment: The belief that the origins of a word dictate (or especially should dictate) modern English usage is erroneous, and has been discussed here before several times. It is called the 'etymological fallacy'. Few people would argue that 'antisemitic' should not be used for 'hating Jews', although Semites include Arabs.

Comment: The reason is we now speak 21st century English and not 2000 year old Latin (yes I know Latin was used in some form or other over many centuries, but that didn't make a pithy sentence). Things have moved on since Romans and monks were making the rules.

Comment: @Zvonimir: Actually, I expect most people have heard of *alternating current* (and presumably know it toggles between precisely TWO directions). But just because the word has *some* "binary" associations doesn't mean it can't have extended usage without them. And just because the present *resembles* the past doesn't mean we should strive to maintain or increase that resemblance. If that was the master plan, we'd still all be pond life after 4 billion years.

Comment: (then again, perhaps relatively speaking, we *are!* :)

Comment: Latin is ahead of you: "Tres Joves memorant, ex quibus primum et secundum natos in Arcadia, alterum patre AEthere." **Adelard** *Id* *et* *Dif.*

Answer (score 3):

The fact that the definition of *alter* is based on only one choice of two means that there is more than one choice...so right here there are two alternatives!

The English word *alternative* may be based on the word *alter*, but in the English usage, there are more than two choices. In fact, there are occasions when there are numerous alternatives from which to choose. For example, if you are looking to buy a car, you can choose between a Ford, a Chevy, a Dodge, etc.  In fact, there are numerous choices of models in each of the brand names.

In this situation you have many alternatives from which to choose.

Answer (score 1):

The reason English speakers permit themselves more than two *alternatives* in some situations is because in English *alternative* has evolved beyond the strict meaning "one of two possible things"—if, indeed, it was ever limited to that strict sense.

The same phenomenon (but in reverse) has occurred with *dilemma*, which many English speakers no longer associate narrowly with "two undesirable choices" (or even earlier with, according to Merriam-Webster, "an argument presenting two or more equally conclusive alternatives against an opponent"), but now readily apply to situations involving a difficult choice or even to situations involving a difficult problem and no identified choice at all.

In short, as various commenters have pointed out above, the meanings of words change organically within the pool of people who speak it; new generations of people grow up using the words in their altered sense, as memory of the earlier meaning fades; and the words become estranged from their roots. Nothing, it seems, could be more natural.